# Subset a dataframe based on input variable

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
 df<-data.frame("EmailReach"<-c(1:20), "MobileReach"<-c(21:40))
 names(df)<-c("EmailReach", "MobileReach")
```

I have listed two variables as follows

```
  Channel<-c("Email", "Mobile")
```

I want to list the individual weighted means for the channel variables.

```
for(i in paste0(Channel, "Reach")) 
{print(min(weighted.mean(df[,names(df)%in%paste0(Channel, "Reach")][i])))}
```

The above code gives me the weighted means but not names of the variable. How do I accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`summarise_all`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) from `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% summarise_all(weighted.mean)

  EmailReach MobileReach
1       10.5        30.5
```